# Using Mockito's argThat() matcher causes "method ambiguous for the type" error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I am trying to mock a method which takes a map and couple other arguments as parameters. My goal is to match the map entries.
Originally I defined my mock as:

```
when(discoveryJobCatalogResourceAccessor.findResource(argThat(allOf(hasEntry("start", "testStart"), hasEntry("level", "testLevel"))), any(Integer.class),
            any(Integer.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(searchResponse);
```

This causes the following error:

> The method findResource(Map<String,String>, Integer, Integer, String, String) is ambiguous for the type DiscoveryJobCatalogResourceAccessor

When I replace `argThat()` with `any(HashMap.class)` like this:

```
when(discoveryJobCatalogResourceAccessor.findResource(any(HashMap.class), any(Integer.class),                any(Integer.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(searchResponse);
```

the error is gone, but in this case I cannot match the map values. It seems that Mockito's `argThat()` causes the ambiguity. I am wondering if there is a way to use the `argThat()` without causing an error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can cast to the required type

```
when(discoveryJobCatalogResourceAccessor.findResource(HashMap<String,String>)argThat(allOf(hasEntry("start", "testStart"), hasEntry("level", "testLevel"))), any(Integer.class),
            any(Integer.class), any(String.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(searchResponse);
```